# Slickgrid render an existing table

Tags: html-table, slickgrid

I have a problem/question with Slickgrid.
On a website I have a big table and i want it to be rendered with slickgrid.
Loading data via JS is not possible.
So my question is, whether it is possible to get the data of a HTML-Table as source for a slickgrid?

And if yes how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SlickGrid suits your needs best here. I think [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) will be better suitable to convert HTML-table data to a formatted grid which supports jQuery.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could also load data by looping through your existing table to create your data variable.

Hide the HTML table
For each row in the table
    Assign cell content to data[rownumber][column_name or number]
next
Then take the populated data variable and feed it to SlickGrid